# Placing an array of jQuery objects into html form elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this array of jQuery objects

```
(2) [{…}, {…}]
0:{Name: "name", NRIC/Passport: "nric", Date of Birth: "2018-06-02", Occupation: "occ", Weight: "123", …}
1:{Name: "name2", NRIC/Passport: "nric2", Date of Birth: "2018-06-02", Occupation: "occ2", Weight: "234", …}
length:2
__proto__:Array(0)
```

I want to place them into html form elements. Currently this is how I do it:

```
$.each(spouses,function(key,value){
       $.each(value,function(int_key,int_value){
       $("#spouse_data").append("<div class='col-sm-4'><label>"+int_key+"</label><input type='text' readonly class='form-control' name='spouse' value="+int_value+"></div>");
    });
});
```

However, I won't be able to set a name for each of the form elements so that I can receive the data when I submit the form. 
There is another option where instead of using this format of object

```
"Name of obj":data
```

I use

```
name_of_obj:data
```

The problem with the second one is that I can't insert label names. I was wondering what the best way of doing this is.

Comment: Those are simple Javascript objects, not *"jQuery objects"*.

Comment: Change your objects to look like this: `{name: { value: 'name', label: 'Name' }, nric: { value: 'nric', label: 'NRIC/Passport' },  …}`

Comment: Oh, how do I iterate through this then?

Comment: Check my answer. This pattern is what you'll be doing all the time in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your objects to an array of objects looking somewhat like this:

```
[{ value: 'name', label: 'Name', name: 'name' }, { value: 'nric', label: 'NRIC/Passport', name: 'nric_password' }]
```

Then iterate over it using `Array.prototype.forEach`:

```js
[{
  value: 'name',
  label: 'Name',
  name: 'name_for_form_submission'
}, {
  value: 'nric',
  label: 'NRIC/Passport',
  name: 'nric_password'
}].forEach((item) => {
  console.log(`${item.label}: ${item.value}, form name: ${item.name}`)
})
```

Comment: So in my case would it be spouses.forEach((item) => {console.log(`${item.label}: ${item.value}, form name: ${item.name}`)
})

Comment: You will have to do more adjustments, I can only get you started here as of how to restructure your objects so you can do what is needed. The learning how to iterate over data etc will have to be done by you.

Answer (score 0):

What about using the following for your form elements:

```
name="spouse[' + index + ']"
```

Does it make sense to use an array field type instead of a string?

Answer (score 0):

check this code, you can do it like this

https://codepen.io/creativedev/pen/pKjamd

```
var obj = {
        0: {Name: "name", "NRIC/Passport": "nric", "Date of Birth": "2018-06-02", Occupation: "occ", Weight: "123"},
        1: {Name: "name2", "NRIC/Passport": "nric2", "Date of Birth": "2018-06-02", Occupation: "occ2", Weight: "234"}
        };
$.each(obj,function(key,value){
    $.each(value,function(key1,value1){
    $("#data").append("<div class='col-sm-4'><label>"+key1+"</label><input type='text' readonly class='form-control' name='spouse' value="+value1+"></div>");
    });
     $("#data").append("<br/><br/>");
});
```